# Xcode "not responding"

Tags: xcode

I'm using XCode 10.1 and Mojave. I've been working with XCode for almost an year now, but recently I encountered a prompt XCode is not responding. I have tried lots of options that I found online, but none of them is working for me.

The scenario is, when I double-click my project from folder to open in XCode, nothing happens, and no window is opened. When I check on the activity monitor, XCode is labelled with some red warning that is not responding. When I open XCode and try to open a project from the File tab, the app freezes at the point of looking in the folder which project to select.

So far these are the options I have tried.

1. I updated my OS from High Sierra to Mojave when this issue emerged.
2. I upgraded my  XCode from version 9 to 10.1.
3. I tried to clean the cache by trashing the folders  `~/Library/Cache/`,  `~/Library/Developer/`.

None of them has really helped me, even after clearing recently opened projects, however I can get the simulator open without an issue, but I can neither compile my app for now nor install it on the simulator.

Comment: Have you tried Time Machining back to a time before the project showed this symptom?

Answer (score 0):

I saw same issue on my device recently. I'm running the latest XCode 13.4 & XCode 14 (beta) on macOS 12.4 (Monterey).

In my case the issue was with **EdenFS**. It is a virtual file-system connected to a network. I previously opened an XCode project from this disk & no longer using it but XCode is still trying to access it in my opinion, which results in this 'Not responding' state.

What I did was 'unmounted' the file system and XCode started to work fine afterwards.

Don't know if it is same for everyone but this is one of the possibilities for someone using this kind of system.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and I used [CleanMyMac](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) App to remove Xcode Junk and it works again.
This [link](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache) helped me.

In steps:

1. I deleted the Xcode from Applications
2. I run from Terminal `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
3. delete all Xcode caches from path /Library/Caches
4. I used the program CleanMyMac to remove all Xcode related files